# Hi, I have a code that updates the game object when they get out of sync but i have to click a GUI button every time i run the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that updates the game object when they get out of sync but i have to click a GUI button every time i run the game. Is there a way i the code can auto run when i run the game.
This is the code for the function that updates the roads:

```
 /// <summary> Updates all roads of this RoadSystem </summary>
    public void UpdateAllRoads()
    {
        Road[] allRoadObjs = GetComponentsInChildren<Road>();
        int roadCount = allRoadObjs.Length;
        SplineC[] piggys = null;
        if (roadCount > 1)
        {
            piggys = new SplineC[roadCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < roadCount; i++)
            {
                piggys[i] = allRoadObjs[i].spline;
            }
        }

        Road road = allRoadObjs[0];
        if (piggys != null && piggys.Length > 0)
        {
            road.PiggyBacks = piggys;
        }
        road.UpdateRoad();
    }
```

This is the code for the button which executes the code:

```
//Update all roads button:
        if (GUILayout.Button("Update all roads", EditorStyles.miniButton, GUILayout.Width(120f)))
        {
            roadSystem.UpdateAllRoads();
        }
```

Comment: put it into [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

Unity has a [Lifecycle System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) in which there are some functions/methods that will be called at a set time, for example `Update()` will be called each frame of the game until the gameObject gets destroyed or get disabled. `OnDisable()` will be called when the object gets disabled.

In order to call your function `UpdateAllRoads()` at the start of the game, call it from `Awake()` or from `Start()`. This way when you start the game this function/method will be called every time.